# Pass Data to a Component in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm having trouble with the syntax on props when passing a data structure to a component in React Native. If anyone could help me see how I can reuse the component 'DisplayPerson' below by passing it 'FemaleInfo' and then again 'MaleInfo' would greatly appreciate it.

```
var FemaleInfo = [
    {name: 'Jane Doe', age: 23, occupation: 'Carpenter'},
    {name: 'Kate Ryan', age: 31, occupation: 'Lawyer'},
    {name: 'Ellen Anderson', age: 42, occupation: 'Doctor'}
];

var MaleInfo = [
    {name: 'John Doe', age: 23, occupation: 'Carpenter'},
    {name: 'Jack Douglas', age: 31, occupation: 'Lawyer'},
    {name: 'Rick Smith', age: 42, occupation: 'Doctor'}
];

var DisplayPerson = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            name: FemaleInfo[0].name,
            age: FemaleInfo[0].age,
            occupation: FemaleInfo[0].occupation
        };
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <Text style={styles.data}>
                {this.state.name}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.data}>
                {this.state.age}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.data}>
                {this.state.occupation}
            </Text>
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a parent component for DisplayPerson. Pass the info from parent to child and use the props in the child component.

Something like:

and use info in DisplayPerson component.

```
render() {
    let info = this.props.info;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.data}>
                {info.name}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.data}>
                {info.age}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.data}>
                {info.occupation}
            </Text>
        </View>)
}
```

Comment: Hmmm working for me. In this example, I just gave a simple example of what I was trying to do, but in the actual code I'm working on, I am using state. Could that be the issue? I am calling it as such...

`<DisplayInfo info={FemaleInfo}/>
<DisplayInfo info={MaleInfo}/>`

And then within the DisplayInfo component:

    `getInitialState: function() {
        let info = this.props.info;
            return {
                   index: i,
            name: info[i].name,
            age: info[i].age,
            occupation: info[i].occupation
         };
    },`

Comment: You can use state for the above example. It will work. But as of my understanding there is no need for it.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me figure it out!